# Sending SMS without using Android's SmsManager .. Native library?

Tags: java, android, sms, native

I have interest in either sending a text message with a modified UDH or sending a binary  data text.

`SmsManager` does not support any access to the UDH and `sendDataMessage` only works on *some* GSM phones and CDMA is completely unsupported.

I have done my fair share of research and have concluded I will need to find a way around the Android standard Library, as bad as that sounds.

My first instinct tells me to do it with native Java and import it into my app. Does anyone know if this will cause issues with Android's security regarding SMS? Also, I am curious how apps like TextPlus work without using the Android API, since they are able to send "texts" without using the phone's standard text messaging.

Comment: This might help you gain insight into this telephony process... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111067/how-does-modem-code-talk-to-android-code/11111953#11111953

Comment: As for TextPlus, its confusing against what you're claiming that it works without phone's standard messaging because in this page [TextPlus/Sms](http://www.textplus.com/sms/) - to quote '*StdMsg&Data Rates May Apply. Message and Data Rates May Apply. To stop receiving textPlus messages from 60611 numbers, text the word STOP to 60611. You can restart later by texting the word START to 60611.*' - which implies you need to text the code - also its seems US/Canada orientated - possibly piggy backing on google voice?

Comment: @t0mm13b that is only the case when the end user does not have TextPlus. If the end user *does* have TextPlus, they will not get the sms in their normal inbox, it will know to forward only to the TextPlus app (I guess this is purely data?)

Comment: Have no idea as am in the EU. And never heard of TextPlus either until now, oddly enough I do not see any FAQ page on that site. So am inclined to believe its using the US carrier-centric Google Voice and exploiting that for the form of texting... sadly Google Voice does not exist outside of the US :(

Comment: It does sound the same as a whatsapp?

Comment: @t0mm13b US-limitation should not be a problem .. also, in a sense, yes it is similar to whatsapp. I would really like to use SMS/MMS/etc to send the text not data (thought it is received as a text either way)

Answer (score -1):

> I have done my fair share of research and have concluded I will need to find a way around the Android standard Library, as bad as that sounds.

If by "find a way around the Android standard Library", you really mean "create my own customized version of the Android OS where I modify it to allow what I want, then convert that custom OS into a ROM mod that I can apply to a relative handful of devices, then create an app that runs on that ROM mod using the capabilities that I exposed", then yes, that is probably what will be required.

> Also I am curious how apps like TextPlus works without using the Android API, since they are able to send "texts" without using the phone's standard text messaging.

I imagine that they use the Internet.

Comment: Keep in mind there are 3rd party SMS Gateways that can forward texts to Carrier's MSC's, I don't need to build another framework for sending texts.