# Communicate with android RIL

Tags: android, ril

I'm looking to get access to get low level network information on an android device that isn't available through the api. Is there a way to talk to the RIL to get more information?

Comment: This might help you - [How does modem code talk to android code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111067/how-does-modem-code-talk-to-android-code/11111953#11111953)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  I'm actually messing around that same thing. My hardware uses GSM radio and everything turns around the android internal API. (do a stackoverflow search with "[android] internal API" and you will get tons of info on how to access it). In my case, I'm interested in the data link over the GSM. So, it's in android source code in frameworks/base/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/DataConnectionTracker.java. If you are interested in other features like SMS, SIM cards, voice call or anything that is not available on the standard "public" API, look in the folders frameworks/base/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony and the names are pretty relevant to what it does. As for a clear documentation, I did not find it. I think it's not publish since it is not recommended to use the internal APIs because it could change without notice and there is no guaranty an internal API will not change in the next Android version.