# Android Conference and Hold Call Programmatically

Tags: android, telephonymanager, conference

How to merge Call programmatically while other call is running. Is it possible to hold and make conference call in android programmatically?. Is anyone please guide me.... I hope someone will guide me in a proper way, Of course I have searched and did R & D for it but could not find any properly Guide.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21515966/881771

Comment: @Gaurav, I tried InCallUI. But it wont run in my system eclipse. It takes so much of time and gives memory out of error.

Comment: Didn't find any code until now but I'm still looking. Anybody have any idea about this. Please share ...

Comment: @Gaurav No mean to see that link you provided because that is completely not possible to do anyhow even that man failed to explain in the comments

Answer (score 1):

You can do these things

- Try [RIL (Radio Interface Layer)](http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/telephony.html) for Call Conference which android use for telephony calls.
- See this que its similar [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951638/how-to-merge-call-programmatically-while-other-call-is-running-conference-call)

Comment: duplicate of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21510666/1741671

Answer (score 0):

There is no api to do so in android, I had [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951638/how-to-merge-call-programmatically-while-other-call-is-running-conference-call) Query

Still did not get any satisfied answer

If you get any clue/suggestions than let me know