# How to merge calls in Android

Tags: merge, phone-call, forwarding

I am working on a call forwarding Android app. Call divert is working very well, but I need to implement call conferencing as well. If I am calling from my number to a second number, then the call should be divert to another number and all three participants should be in conference conference. I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this as of now. You can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951638/how-to-merge-call-programmatically-while-other-call-is-running-conference-call). However you can make conference call using [VOIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP).

These are some VOIP providers:

1. [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/)
2. [Plivo](https://www.plivo.com/)
3. [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/get-started)