# how to merge call programmatically in android- conference-call

Tags: android

I am working on an android app that auto-call/auto-dial 5 people and put them in conference call programmatically, The calls are GSM (local calls from my number to another 5 phone numbers)

Till now what I have studied I found that currently there is no API in android SDK with which one can merge call programmatically.

Still I am looking for solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way to merge normal phone calls. You can merge only VoIP calls. PS: I think you mean "programmatically" and not "problematically" :P

Comment: lol yeah programmatically :P  actually as I have mentioned that I know there is no support in android sdk but still looking for some hack

Comment: it is possible by using 'InCallService'

Comment: @Vineesh TP Did you have some reference for  'InCallServices' ?

Comment: @NikolaLukic: Set your app as default phone app in android phone. Then you will get  all call back in extended "InControlservice'.  Android Documentation : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService.html

Comment: Sorry ,  in my case only SIM based calls is interest for me. Is it real impossible to make more than one number : See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951638/how-to-merge-call-programmatically-while-other-call-is-running-conference-call

Comment: Looks like not clear situation ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge Call programmatically while other call is running (Conference call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951638/how-to-merge-call-programmatically-while-other-call-is-running-conference-call)