# Android - how to merge calls (GSM/SIM) to conference (InCallService)

Tags: android, system-calls, phone-call

I'm trying to merge two GSM calls into conference programmatically.

In `Call` class is method `conference()` but I'm not sure how to correctly work with it. I tried several ways but nothing work successfully.

I have class `CallService` (implements `InCallService`)

And in method `override fun onCallAdded(call: Call)`

I tried something like this:

```
    activeCall.hold()

    secondCall.answer(VideoProfile.STATE_AUDIO_ONLY)

    secondCall.conference(activeCall) 
    secondCall.mergeConference()
```

But it will not create a conference call (the first call is set as busy). I tried several changes in that code but nothing work.

I also find this [how to merge call programmatically in android- conference-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074101/how-to-merge-call-programmatically-in-android-conference-call) and this [How to merge Call programmatically while other call is running (Conference call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951638/how-to-merge-call-programmatically-while-other-call-is-running-conference-call?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it's not helped (and it's a little old)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this two method to merge calls.
[**Call.conference**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call#conference(android.telecom.Call)) and [**Call.mergeConference**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call#mergeConference()) method.

You can see the basic examples of inCallService api in this project. **https://github.com/HiddenPirates/Dialer**