# How to properly implement Call.conference (Android API 23+) with GSM calls?

Tags: android, call, gsm, conference

I'm trying to create conference call using Call.conference(Call callToConferenceWith) and this function do nothing…

Does anyone advise me how to properly implement this function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge Call programmatically while other call is running (Conference call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951638/how-to-merge-call-programmatically-while-other-call-is-running-conference-call)

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767460/answer-incoming-call-using-android-telecom-and-incallservice (that one seems a little newer).

Comment: @Martin Zeitler I have created a functional InCallService. I accept and terminate calls, put it on hold. The only thing that does not work is a conference call. Not one of the links offers me the answer to my question ...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ...you ask about an implementation, which not showing what you have tried so far - and without providing the least context, you might not get any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the necessary information and implementation can be found at this link: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/InCallUI/+/android-5.0.1_r1/src/com/android/incallui (Do not be afraid this is an implementation for Android 5.0.1+. All the necessary implementations are essentially the same.)

For you, important files are InCallPresenter.java and TelecomAdapter.java

Enjoy conference calls with Android ;)

Comment: Yes. You're right. It can be read almost everything. After minor modifications, the code is fully functional. Thank you.